# How can I set the image for app introduction's background in Apple TV app store

Tags: app-store, tvos, apple-tv

I have developed and published one TVOS app. In my app project, I put icon images, launch image and top shelf image. I also put two screenshots in the app configuration part on the developer.apple.com.

Now the app is online. The top shelf image is fine when the app is in focus. But the top shelf image is not used as the background image in the App introduction part in the App Store. I want to get the full background like the game app. Where shall I configure that image and what is the dimension of the image? Thanks in advance! I attach images to make my questions more clear.

My app looks like this when it is focused on the Apple TV. I want to use this topshelf image for the app introduction background.
[image]

But it looks like this in the app store. I don't want to see the screenshot on the right side of the screen. There is no background image at the introduction part.

[image]

I want to get the full-background for the introduction page like this app.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have no control over that. Only apps selected by Apple's App Store editors are given the privilege to have a customized App Store page.

Note, the standard background on the Apple TV App Store, is created automatically based on your app's icon. It's a large, blurred out version of your icon. So in your case, you see that red line, and a lot of white, which is exactly what you have in your icon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! Now I understand :)